# Why does `=~` behave differently than `eq` and `==` in list context?

Tags: regex, perl

Consider

```perl
my @array = ( 'x' =~ /y/, 'x' eq 'y', 1 == 2 );
```

and

```perl
my %hash = ( 'a', 'x' =~ /y/, 'b', 'x' eq 'y', 'c', 1 == 2 );
```

Using `Data::Dumper`, we see that `=~` behaves differently than `eq` and `==`

```perl
\@array = [
            '',
            ''
          ];
```

```perl
\%hash = {
           'a' => 'b',
           '' => undef
         };
```

Specifically it appears that the snippets of code above are being interpreted as

```perl
my @array = ( 'x' eq 'y', 1 == 2 );
```

and

```perl
my %hash = ( 'a', 'b', 'x' eq 'y', 'c', 1 == 2 );
```

Can someone provide an explanation for this arguably unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The match operation you use is not only about finding out if something has matched (scalar context) but also to give the match results (list context). To cite from [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Matching-in-list-context):

> Matching in list context
> m// in list context returns a list consisting of the subexpressions matched by the parentheses in the pattern, that is, ($1, $2, $3...) (Note that here $1 etc. are also set). When there are no parentheses in the pattern, the return value is the list (1) for success. With or without parentheses, **an empty list is returned upon failure**